# typing.get_type_hints returns Union instead of Optional

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I'm trying to extract some nice human-readable type hints from Python functions, but `typing.get_type_hints()` is returning something more complex/less readable than I was expecting.

For example:

```py
import typing

def say_something(something: str = None):
     print(something)

typing.get_type_hints(say_something)
```

What I *want* it to give me is:

```py
{'something': Optional[str]}
```

And [according to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints), that is indeed what should be happening:

> If necessary, `Optional[t]` is added for function and method annotations if a default value equal to `None` is set.

But what it *actually* returns is this, which is equivalent but less readable:

```py
{'something': typing.Union[str, NoneType]}
```

Other than manually substituting `typing.Union[{x}, NoneType]` with `Optional[{x}]`, is there any way to get these nicer type hints in Python 3? (I'm on 3.7.5 specifically.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK `Optional[smth]` will always return `Union[smth, NoneType]`, so basically there is no separate `Optional` type annotation, it just an alias/shorthand.

If we take a look at [`typing` module source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/typing.py)

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/df8913f7c48d267efd662e8ffd9496595115eee8/Lib/typing.py#L369-L371

we can see that when we are calling `Optional[smth]` what gets returned is `Union[smth, NoneType]`.

We can also check this in REPL

```py
>>> from typing import Optional
>>> Optional[str]
typing.Union[str, NoneType]
```